# Delete a line from a file using java

Tags: java, file

I am just a beginner in java programming and  trying to write a code to delete a specific line from a java file.

Here i am using scanner class to read the file and printwriter class coupled with FileWriter to write to the temporary file. I want to know what is the mistake I have made in the code. There are no syntax errors.

Here "u" is the original file containing the text whereas "t" is the temporary file to where the contents of the file are copied and later is renamed to the original file. In the function "int ldel is the index of line to be deleted. suppose the file is as :

```
  aaa
  bbb
  ccc
```

now if the value of ldel is passed as 2 then the file must be formatted as :

```
 aaa
 ccc
```

I have thought a lot and could not find a single logical error. Please tell me if you find one.The coding was as follows :

```
void deleteline(int ldel)throws IOException
{
   Scanner dr=new Scanner(u);
   FileWriter fwd= new FileWriter(t,true);
   PrintWriter pd= new PrintWriter(fwd,true);
   int c=0;
   while(dr.hasNextLine()==true)
   {
       c++;
       if(c!=ldel)
       pd.println(dr.nextLine());
       else if(c==ldel)
       continue;

    }
    t.renameTo(u);
    u.delete();
    dr.close();
    fwd.close();
    pd.close();
}
```

Comment: You would do your future self, your colleagues and us a big favor by using descriptive variables names. If your `u` was called something like `originalFile`, you would't need to explain what it was. The same applies for all variable names.

Comment: You don't call next line everytime. That should be in your else. `else{ dr.nextLine();}` throw away that line.

Answer (score 1):

You should invoke `nextLine()` even if you don't want to output it, otherwise it's processed at the next iteration of the loop.

Change the loop like this:

```
while (dr.hasNextLine()) {
    c++;
    String line = dr.nextLine();
    if (c != ldel) {
        pd.println(line);
    }
}
```

No need to use `continue`.

Also I think you should delete the `u` file before renaming `t`.

Answer (score 0):

[1] You rename file with name 't' to a new name, 'u'.. and then you delete the file named 'u'. That doesn't sound right.

[2] when your 'if' skips over the nextLine statement, you don't consume a line at all, which means you still get ALL the lines in the output file. So, even when c == ldel, you need to invoke .readLine() to get rid of it.

[3] On various file systems, renaming an open file does not work. The close calls should be placed before you rename.

[4] 'else if (ldel==c)' is superfluous; a mere 'else' would do. For that matter, the continue is superfluous, continue just means end the loop here and go back to the start. It does literally nothing whatsoever if it's the last thing in the loop. It's the last thing in your loop. Get rid of it entirely. This doesn't change what your code does, but it does make your code easier to understand.

[5] when opening files for reading/writing. you should be explicit about the charset. FileWriter doesn't let you. Don't use that class. Look into the new file API and use something like `Files.newInputStream`, note you'd have to change most of this code to use the new API, and this is an optional style suggestion.

[6] you should use the try-with-resources construct (search the web for 'java try-with-resources' if you don't know what this is). The problem with this code is that it leaks resources when exceptions occur. For a throwaway app (as in, it runs, does one thing, and then exits) this does not matter, but if you place this code in a larger construct (say, for example, this is part of a webserver), it'll eventually take down the entire VM. Best to get into the proper practice of always opening resources via the try-with-resources construct.

Answer (score 0):

Although your code is not the best implementation of the logic, if you  want to fix your code you should call `nextLine()` method in `c==ldel` condition in order to ignore the line. So your loop should be like this:

```
   while(dr.hasNextLine()==true)
   {
       c++;
       if(c!=ldel)
           pd.println(dr.nextLine());
       else if(c==ldel)
       {
            dr.nextLine()
            continue;
       }


    }
```